# Why can i go to www.domain.com/index.php/put_anything_here?

Tags: php, html

Why is it possible to go further into my index.php file as it was a folder like: www.domain.com/index.php/**put_anything_here_and_it_loads_the_file_without_styling**

I want it to use the .htaccess to redirect them to the index.php when they go to a file that does not exist like index.php/anything_here - but for some reason it thinks that index.php/anything_here exists...

Right now i have just set my .htaccess to redirect to this page if one of the errors happen:

This is my .htaccess:

```
ErrorDocument 404 /404error.php
ErrorDocument 400 /404error.php
ErrorDocument 401 /404error.php
ErrorDocument 403 /404error.php
ErrorDocument 500 /404error.php
```

Thanks

Comment: Could you paste a copy of your htaccess?

Comment: Right now i just set up so all the diffrent errors go to the same error page:

ErrorDocument 404 /404error.php
ErrorDocument 400 /404error.php
ErrorDocument 401 /404error.php
ErrorDocument 403 /404error.php
ErrorDocument 500 /404error.php

Comment: Hmm. Sometimes apps like WordPress route everything through index.php and have that return responses but it doesn't look like your htaccess does that. Maybe try put test data in index.php and visit a non existing page. If the dummy data shows you know something is routing requests to index.php otherwise your web server might be misconfigured.

Comment: The data shows when I go to fx. Index.php/anything. So it must be routing request to index.php. Do you know how to fix that problem?

Comment: I'm sorry but without knowledge of your development set up or the application you're using it's really difficult to suggest what it could be. If I were you I'd take a look your web server configuration and work your way from there.